# Trying to migrate

Tags: python, migration

I am trying to migrate my project on my virtual environment for the very first time and this is the message.

```
python manage.py migrate 

traceback(most recent call last):
File "manage.py"line 21, in <module>
main()
```

and there are very statements similar to the one above and it finishes with the last message

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.operationalerror
```

My virtual environment running with

- django 2.2.2
- psycopg2 2.8.3
- pytz 2019.1
- sqlparse 0.3.0
- python3.7
- pip 19.1.1

on windows 7

unable to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add the full error and in copy and paste?

We can't really help if we don't see the error type.

Also, try this

```
 $ python manage.py makemigrations
 $ python manage.py sqlmigrate
 $ python manage.py migrate
```

This worked for me.

If that doesn't work, update everything (python, django, pip, and other packages)